# Get the value of input text when enter key pressed

Tags: javascript, html, input, keycode

I am trying this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search" onkeydown="search()"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search" onkeydown="search()"/>
```

with some javascript to check whether the enter key is pressed:

```
function search() {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("should get the innerHTML or text value here");
    }
}
```

this works fine at the moment, but my question how to get the value inside the text field, I was thinking of passing a reference "this" to the function, or if they had id's then I could use ID's but then I don't see how I could differentiate between which one has been typed, bringing my back to the same problem again...

Comment: You can pass `this` and get `this.value` for the current target/textfield!

Comment: *"should get the innerHTML* inputs do not have innerHTML...

Comment: yeah I should have tried passing this first, thank you for the confirmation though.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search" onkeydown="search(this)"/>  
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search" onkeydown="search(this)"/>
```

**JS Code**

```
function search(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        alert(ele.value);        
    }
}
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/iKoZaja/1/)**

Comment: First I thought there was an error in it, then I tried: Works perfectly and is the finest vanilly approach I could find. Thx.

Comment: Just a quick change for someone who might find this by any chance, in HTML5 it should be onkeypress instead of onkeydown and event.keyCode == 13 for 'Enter' key.

Comment: Also, in HTML5, 'search(this)' should be 'search(event)', from which you read 'ele.keyCode === 13' to get whether Enter was pressed. keyword 'this' doesn't work.

Comment: `onkeypress` and `keyCode` both deprecated... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 22):

```
$("input").on("keydown",function search(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/NH8K2/1/

Comment: Isn't it jQuery version. But I guess he want solution in plane javascript.

Comment: or use jQuery, that is also a great answer, thank you, I opted for normal Javascript, but this is just as awesome, thank you :)

Comment: sorry when I said "or use jQuery", I meant that everyone is giving a pure javascript solution and this is a jquery solution, in a jokey tone...

Answer (score 12):

Just using the event object

```
function search(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var elem = e.srcElement || e.target;
        alert(elem.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe exactly what this function does.

Answer (score 4):

Listen the `change` event.

```
document.querySelector("input")
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    const $myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

    $myInput.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.key === 'Enter') {
            alert($myInput.value);        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not place Javascript code in your HTML, since you're giving those input a class ("search"), there is no reason to do this. A better solution would be to do something like this :

```
$( '.search' ).on( 'keydown', function ( evt ) {
    if( evt.keyCode == 13 )
        search( $( this ).val() ); 
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested, but should work)

Pass this as parameter in Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search" onkeydown="search(this)"/>
```

And alert the value of the parameter passed into the search function:

```
function search(e){
  alert(e.value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  const searchInput =  document.getElementById('urlInput');

searchInput.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
    console.log(e.key)
    if(e.key == 13){
        const elem =  e.target
        console.log(elem.value);
    }
})
```

```html
<input id="urlInput" type="text" placeholder="some text" class="search"/>
```