# On Enter fire javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, enter

After reading this post here in Stackoverflow, ([Detect the Enter key in an text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060750/detect-the-enter-key-in-an-text-input-field/7060762#7060762)) I tried to make a few of my inputs fire on enter... I did not work. I made a simple example and it still doesn't work. Can someone hint as to the proper way? (FYI - Definitely a newbie here)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>On Enter</title>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script> 
<script>
        $(".input1").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                alert ("It Works");
            }
        });
</script>

</head>

<body>


        <input type="text"
            id="input1"
            placeholder="Press Enter When Done">
        </input>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code must be AFTER the HTML so the DOM is available when it runs.  Or, you can use `$(document).ready(...) to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Comment: Duplicate, 
check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998541/get-the-value-of-input-text-when-enter-key-pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to say `#input1` other than `.input1`, then run it when the entire DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input1").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert ("It Works");
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**: As *@jfriend00* mentioned in a comment it's a good idea to use `e.which` other than `e.keycode`. To do so you can change: `e.keyCode == 13` to `e.which == 13`. This way is recommenced by the people at jQuery, as it normalizes `e.keyCode` and `e.charCode`.

Comment: The only complete answer so far that fixes BOTH problems in the OP's code to make it actually work.  I think you actually may want to use [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of `e.keyCode` to take advantage of jQuery's event normalization among different browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and tutorial. I am still learning and concise answer/tutorials are great. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `.input1` in your JS to `#input1`

When you use `.` it means it's a class, but you have an ID, which is `#`.

Comment: The code is running before the DOM is parsed.  This fix is not sufficient.

Comment: @Soren Although what you said in the edit is correct, it was never intended by the author of this post. Which is why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- did you not think it improved the answer?   What the original author intended is actually irrelevant, and what is important is to improve the site answers -- you could have done that as well instead of adding a new answer.

Comment: @Soren [Refer to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts), I understand that you want to make this answer better. And yes I agree it does improve the post. Although it changes the meaning of the post. Edits are to make things cleaner and easier to understand, not to append more information to. Also note I was still typing on my answer before I saw this post. What if I removed the entire answer from the author and gave a new one in an edit because I think it improved the post? I'm sure the author would not like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is triggering a "class", not an "id", so add a "#" instead of a "." in input1:

```
       $("#input1").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                alert ("It Works");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first, like the previous answer your criteria is not good. change for ID
second, put your javascript at the and of the file on in the ready document. 
Because the javascript is in execution while the documenta as not finish to load . So the event can't be add to an element that doesnt exist.