# get the value of input text when enter key

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

how i can get the value of input text when enter key pressed in this cod ?
.....................................................................

```
<body>
  <div id="center">
    <div id="boxtop"></div> 

    <div id="boxdown"> 
      <input type="text" id="txt"/>
      <button type="submit"  onclick="SaveData()" id="btn" >SEND</button>
    </div> 

  </div> 
  <script>
    function SaveData() {
        work = "insert";
        chat = $('#txt').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server.php",
            data: "work="+work+"&chat="+chat,
            success: function(msg){
                 $('#txt').val('');
                }
            });
        }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the value of input text when enter key pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998541/get-the-value-of-input-text-when-enter-key-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a form around your button and input. Then you can handle both events with

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    SaveData();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This code is for Ajax !
If my form, I will reload my page

Comment: You can cancel the event  with `return false;`  at the end ;) Or you can use `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire an event with ajax function you do not need submit button.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
   preventDefault(); ....
```

**Why you submit the form and then prevent submit?**

It is better to do this:

```
   $(document).keydown(function (e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
          SaveData();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#txt').keypress(function (e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
          chat = $('#txt').val();
      }
  });
```

Comment: I added this code to the first source but did not work

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the same code. Once you hit enter after typing something it alerts with the text that you typed. https://jsfiddle.net/wf6o4wpf/